Turbo rails broadcast_refresh_to does not connect to stimulus controller
Using turbo 8.0.4.
Blog model:
  after_update_commit lambda { |blog| }
    broadcast_refresh_to blog
  }

In blogs/show.html.erb
<%= turbo_stream_from @blog %>
<%= tag.div data: {controller: "blogs"} do %>
  <!-- more content here -->
<% end %>

In blogs_controller.js, I have logic to re-initilize few components in connect method.
broadcast_refresh_to blog refreshes page successfully but does not execute the connect method in stimulus controller due to morphing.
How to fix this issue ?

https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/events#page-refreshes
I can think of one workaround solution to listen to turbo:morph event and do the reinitialization in stimulus controller, but that doesn't seem to be a good solution as this kind of morphed refreshes breaking multiple stimulus controllers in my app.

I found another neat solution for this issue.
Just add yield(:head) to your layout.html.erb:
<!-- app/views/layouts/application.html.erb -->

<html>
  <head><%= yield :head %></head>
  <body><%= yield %></body>
</html>

Then add one of the following methods to your page:
turbo_page_requires_reload

or
turbo_refreshes_with(method: :replace, scroll: :reset)

Now, once you visit your page or send a broadcast_refresh_to command, it will be fully reloaded, resulting in the reconnection of Stimulus controllers.
More details here: https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/main/app/helpers/turbo/drive_helper.rb
